# Meteor/Mongo: $in not working to retrieve users groups

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to return all groups that the current user is a part of. Each user has a groups field that's simply an array of id's for the groups the user belongs to. Here's what my code looks like:

My server method for returning the correct groups

```
userGroups: function(){
    var currentUser = Meteor.users.find({_id: Meteor.userId()});
    return Groups.find({_id: { $in: currentUser.groups}});
}
```

Then the call to that method in my helper:

```
groups: function(){
    return Meteor.call('userGroups');
}
```

I've tried debugging this in the console but I'm just getting more confused. I can call `var user = Meteor.users.find(_id: Meteor.userId())` and it correctly assigns the current user to the variable, but then when I call `user.groups` (which is the array of group id's) it says it's undefined. If I check the document in the meteor mongo command line interface, the current user has a groups field with group id's in it.

Answer (score 1):

find query in Meteor returns a cursor which is not an array, but an object.

You should add .fetch() or use findOne().

```
userGroups: function(){
    var currentUser = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: Meteor.userId()});
// or use var currentUser = Meteor.users.find({_id: Meteor.userId()}).fetch();
    return Groups.find({_id: { $in: currentUser.groups}});
}
```

This should work!

### Update on publishing groups form Meteor.users collection

To add groups from Meteor.users collection to your Meteor.user() auto-publish which acccounts-password package does, you need to include that into a null publication.

Something like this:

```
Meteor.publish(null, function () {
        if (!this.userId) return this.ready();
        return Meteor.users.find({_id: this.userId}, {
            fields: {
                profile : 1,
                emails  : 1,
                groups  : 1
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Should be `.fetch()[0]`

Comment: Still not working. There's something wrong with the way i'm calling the method because even when I change the userGroups method on the server to just return all groups `return Groups.find()`, nothing is returned when I call it within the groups helper. If I however change the groups helper to `return Groups.find()` it does return all groups (which is not what I want, just wanted to see what's working and what's not).

Comment: Ok, so i would guess that you have autopublish removed and your have groups key in your users collection. If this is the case, groups key would not be auto-published for security reasons. I am going to update my answer about how you can include groups

Comment: @Eli, have a look now!

Comment: That was one of the problems. I had not made the groups field available to the client. The other problem was that custom meteor methods aren't reactive by default. I should have been using the built in publish method (which is reactive) to only make the correct groups available to the client.  Once I did that, all problems solved. Thanks so much for the help @Guns